# PageContext in SharePoint Framework

Tags: angularjs, spfx

We all know that `_spPageContextInfo` is a very useful thing in Client side development. I need something equivalent of `_spPageContextInfo` in **SPFX**. Currently I am unable to use it directly from typescript. It gives error like

> Can not find '_spPageContextInfo'

Finally, I have gone through the API documentation of [SharePoint Framework](https://sharepoint.github.io/) and  found [PageContext](https://sharepoint.github.io/classes/_sp_client_base_.pagecontext.html). `PageContext` has dependence with [ServiceScope](https://sharepoint.github.io/classes/_sp_client_base_.servicescope.html). My qestion is: How to use `PageContext`? I need to use it my `BaseService` class. `constructor` of my class is:

```
constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService, serviceScope: ServiceScope) {
    serviceScope.whenFinished(() => {
      this.pageContext = new PageContext(serviceScope);
      console.log(this.pageContext);
    });
  }
```

Inside the `constructor` `serviceScope` is `undefined`. I know the reason: *As I am not injecting/initialising `serviceScope` anywhere like other angular services*. So what is the approach of injecting/initialising `serviceScope` in angular service class?

Comment: But ``window._spPageContextInfo`` **is** available in the Browser for Modern Experiences and Microsoft packed it with loads more goodies compared to the Classic _spPageContextInfo; So why would you want an alternative?

Comment: tried that already. gulp does not compile my code if I use it. Error: **Property '_spPageContextInfo' does not exist on type 'Window'**

Comment: Ah yes, the joys of TypeScript, You now have to write an Interface to the window object that is already there (and available as usual once TS is Transpiled to JS) But at least you are using a cool language and writing 8 more lines of code... Or go F* TS and try ``eval('window._spPageContextInfo')``

Comment: Big YES!! Single line becomes multiple lines. **CEWP** vs **SPFX**

Comment: But SPFx is soooo cool... MVPs tell me  I am a better Front-End Developer now.  because (after 20 years) I no longer have to write 'roque' JavaScript. (Note: TypeScripts has its place in the stack, but it is HypeScript at the moment.. if you look at SPFx code in Github, 20% of it is plain stupid and bloated ECMAScript code inside a TS wrapper because 'MVPs' do not understand things *like* the ``map`` method of an Array and are still stuck in the ``for`` loop era of 15 years ago.)

Comment: Haven't used TS much yet, but can't you just add the _spPageContextInfo to the Window interface? `interface Window { _spPageContextInfo:any}`

Comment: It can be accessed like `(<any>window)._spPageContextInfo`. Thanks for your time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/30740935/1294606

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enjoyed reading the comments on this one (all good points, and I will add the level of abstraction it adds when you are trying to debug!) :-) Anyway, I believe this is what you are looking for*:

```
//import { IWebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-client-preview'; // Old dcumentation refers to this.
import { IWebPartContext} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
```

And then you can do (*assume the context has the stuff you are looking for in):

```
public context: IWebPartContext;
```

And then, for example:

```
url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SomeList')/
```

Answer (score 1):

We are in the process of mapping the various properties on spPageContextInfo into a well typed collection of objects that will hang off the context.  The start of this is accessible via this.context.pageContext in your webpart code.

Also - OnInit might be a better place to put initialization code rather than the constructor.

Comment: `OnInit ` of what? I need it inside angular service class.

Comment: Are you running Angular 1 or 2?  Note that you don't want to be the person creating the page context, the framework should be doing that and making it available.

Comment: I am using Angular 1.X

Comment: First - have you read Waldek's blog post on Angular 1 and SPFX - https://blog.mastykarz.nl/load-angular-templates-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts/ ?
Second, I imagine that you are trying to pass some context to a separate object.  So wherever you are creating the target object should be outside your WebPart constructor.  Lots of stuff doesn't exist at this point (like the context, the webpart properties, etc.).  If you create the object later you can pass those context objects in, or if you store a reference at creation time, you can assign the context objects later (like onInit).

Comment: Here's another post on Angular 1 + SPFx.  https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/SharePoint-PnP-Webcast--Building-Angular-SharePoint-Framework-Client-Web-Part