# SPFx - How to get current user properties with PnP-JS-Core

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spcontext, pnp-js-core

I want to get current user login name with PnP-Core-Library for SPFx in Office365.

My page is modern Page [аnd I can not use it _spContextPageInfo](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Using-sp-pnp-js-in-SharePoint-Framework)

How to do this?

Comment: did you check [this](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/reference/spfx/sp-page-context/class/spuser)?

Comment: also check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198652/pagecontext-in-sharepoint-framework)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use it by doing the following

```
import  Web  from 'sp-pnp-js';

let web = new Web(this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl);
let curruser = web.currentUser.get().then(function(res){ 
console.log(res.Title); })
```