# getting current logged in user in SP list

Tags: spfx-webparts

I have made one webpart using spfx, on submit button its values are  pushing in SP list but in SP list I want user who is currently logged in, its value should come in one of the field of Sp list, how to do in spfx.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want to view Display name of current user when you click on button

Comment: @Melad, yes I want to display its name in one of field of SP list

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the community [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/222091/spfx-how-to-get-current-user-properties-with-pnp-js-core), you could retrieve the current user information before pushing your data into the your list.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve current user information as below:

```
console.log(this.context.pageContext.user.displayName);
console.log(this.context.pageContext.user.loginName);
```

Here `this` is a web part context.

Comment: the above commands works when the field which stores current user name in SP list is of single line of text but when I am making it person or group type then value is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

this solution may help you to get Display name of current user when you click on button

```
public _getCurrentUser(): void{
if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {
  console.log(this.context.pageContext.user.displayName);
  let User = this.context.pageContext.user.displayName;
  let html: string = '';
  html = `
    <ul class="${styles.list}">
      <li class="${styles.listItem}">
        <span class="ms-font-l">${User}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>`;
  const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#SPList');
  listContainer.innerHTML = html;
} }
 private _setButtonEventHandlers(): void {
const webPart: UserClickWebPart = this;
this.domElement.querySelector('#GetUser').addEventListener('click', () => { this._getCurrentUser(); });}
public render(): void {
this.domElement.innerHTML = `
  <div class="${ styles.userClick }">
    <div class="${ styles.container }">
      <div class="${ styles.row }">
        <div class="${ styles.column }">
          <span class="${ styles.title }">Welcome to SharePoint!</span>
          <p class="${ styles.subTitle }">Customize SharePoint experiences using Web Parts.</p>
          <p class="${ styles.description }">${escape(this.properties.description)}</p>
          <button class="${styles.button}" id="GetUser">
          <span class="${styles.label}">CurrentUser</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div id="Global" class="${styles.container}">
        <div id="SPList"></div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>`;
this._setButtonEventHandlers();}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to set the value of a field in a list item to be the current user.

You update a Person or Group field the same way you update a lookup field. That is, you set the value of the field to the Id of target item. In the case of a Person or Group field, that's the Id of the user.

You can get the Id of the current user using the `userId` property legacy page context, which is the same information that's included in the `_spPageContextInfo` object in classic pages. In an SPFx web part, you can get the Id of the current user like this `this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.userId`.

Once you have the Id, you can then write code like this to add a list item that populates the Person or Group field value. In the sample below, the internal name of the Person or Group field is Person.

```
private addItemButtonClickHandler(): void {
  let restUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
    "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CurrentUserSpfx')/items";
    
  let request: any = {};
  request.body = JSON.stringify({
    Title: "Item " + new Date().toUTCString(),
    PersonId: this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.userId
  });

  this.context.spHttpClient.post(restUrl, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, request)
    .then((response) => {
      response.text().then((data) => {
        let addItemResultDiv = this.domElement.querySelector("#addItemResultDiv");
        addItemResultDiv.innerHTML += data;
      });
    });
}
```