# _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl is undefined

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, jsom, typescript, react

The `_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` is undefined which i'm using to acquire information about the web parts on a page. unfortunately, the value always returns undefined. I tried using the following.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js','SP.ClientContext',this.function);
```

When that is executed I get a undefined error for the `spPageContextInfo`.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js','SP.PageContextInfo',this.function);
```

When I run the statement with `SP.PageContextInfo` then the function is never executed. This is all done using typescript and React on Render. I feel as if this is a simple issue but seem to have exhausted most resources.

How to initialize the `_spPageContextInfo` without a race condition for a web part that is run on SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1):

We need add the code below into the page.

```
 <SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
```

Full code of aspx page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register tagprefix="SharePoint" namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">

<head runat="server">
<meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="default" runat="server"/>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,WikiField,_dlc_DocId,_dlc_DocIdUrl,_dlc_DocIdPersistId"><xml>

<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">5JSTYM4NXMKN-1550736763-35</mso:_dlc_DocId>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">11042d2a-78f3-4163-b78b-a7e5c9bdbf00</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>
<mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://sp2013/sites/team/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=5JSTYM4NXMKN-1550736763-35, 5JSTYM4NXMKN-1550736763-35</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    alert(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="FormDigest1" runat="server"></SharePoint:FormDigest>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

If you want to use JSOM code, we need load some JavaScript files:

```
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
```

More information: [Bare minimum page to get _spPageContextInfo loaded](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116359/bare-minimum-page-to-get-sppagecontextinfo-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, but it was caught during build as I am using `CreateReactApp`, and they have a check for no undefined variables.  Their suggestion (and it worked for me) is that you redefine `_spPageContextInfo` like so:

```
const _spPageContextInfo = window._spPageContextInfo;
```

That's it, then just use `_spPageContextInfo` as you normally would.

FWIW I put that line of code after my imports, but before any of the component code, but I suppose it would work from within the render function as well.

Comment: I gave the above code snippet a whirl. Unfortunately, `window._spPageContextInfo` is returning a typescript error that states `_spPageContextInfo` doesn't exist on type `window`

Answer (score 0):

just load the scripts first before you start using the JS code block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script>

SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js','SP.ClientContext',this.function); 


</script>
```

**edit**

sorry missed the spfx part!

```
import { IWebPartContext} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
```

And then you can do (*assume the context has the stuff you are looking for in):

```
public context: IWebPartContext;
```

And then, for example:

```
url = this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('SomeList')/
```

[PageContext in SharePoint Framework](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198652/pagecontext-in-sharepoint-framework)

in spfx you are simply replacing:

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl
```

with

```
this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl
```

Comment: Since i'm using react and typescript I have a `manifest.json` that loads all the scripts that I use before ever executing the script code.

Comment: sorry missed that part lol. is this in debug? if so this should do it.... import { IWebPartContext} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

Comment: the you can.... public context: IWebPartContext; and use the context. taken from here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198652/pagecontext-in-sharepoint-framework